# How to save keras recommenderNet model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After building the model from Embedding RecommenderNet model, how to save it, link to the doc is https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/collaborative_filtering_movielens/

```
class RecommenderNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_users, num_movies, embedding_size, **kwargs):
        super(RecommenderNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_users = num_users
        self.num_movies = num_movies
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.user_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_users,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.user_bias = layers.Embedding(num_users, 1)
        self.movie_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_movies,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.movie_bias = layers.Embedding(num_movies, 1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        user_vector = self.user_embedding(inputs[:, 0])
        user_bias = self.user_bias(inputs[:, 0])
        movie_vector = self.movie_embedding(inputs[:, 1])
        movie_bias = self.movie_bias(inputs[:, 1])
        dot_user_movie = tf.tensordot(user_vector, movie_vector, 2)
        # Add all the components (including bias)
        x = dot_user_movie + user_bias + movie_bias
        # The sigmoid activation forces the rating to between 0 and 1
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)


model = RecommenderNet(num_users, num_movies, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
)
history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=5,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

tried these

```
model.save('model.h5py')
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, save_format='h5')
```

Both throws

```
NotImplementedError: Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be a Functional model or 
a Sequential model.It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of 
a Python method, which isn't safely serializable. Consider saving to the Tensorflow SavedModel 
format (by setting save_format="tf") or using `save_weights`.
```

model type is **main**.RecommenderNet

Comment: is the `h5py` format required?

Comment: no, it can be any format

Comment: Then have you tried `model.save('path-to-save-to')`

Comment: yes, that didn't work either

Comment: tried pickle as well, that throws 'NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.'

Answer (score 1):

So as the error says, you can use `save_format="tf"` since your model is not `Functional` or `Sequential`:

```
model.save('model.py')
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, save_format='tf')
```

Also as seen in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/save_and_load) you can use:

```
keras_model_path = "/tmp/keras_save"
model.save(keras_model_path)
```

Comment: model.py throws same error, and, as 'tf' throws NotImplementedError: Saving the model as SavedModel is not supported in TensorFlow 1.Xgraph mode. Please enable eager execution or use the "h5" save format.

Comment: @hanzgs You are using tensorflow 1?

Comment: Have you tried the model.save() function, without a file ending?

Comment: @jonas I already suggested that in comment but OP said it didn't work

Comment: @skrrrt I've seen this, but the file ending can do the trick

Comment: See if [this tensorflow 1.x doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/guide/saved_model.md) helps you

Comment: yes, got this, model.save_weights("model.h5") worked

Comment: @hanzgs it sure would be usefull if you write an answer, so others can see what helped you.

Comment: I have saved the weights, but not sure how to load it, load_weights need the model initialization right

Comment: can the model be reinitialised to load_weights, like 

model = RecommenderNet(num_users, num_movies, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
)

Answer (score 1):

Actually recreating the model with

```
keras.models.load_model('path_to_my_model')
```

didn't work for me
First we have to save_weights from the built model

```
model.save_weights('model_weights', save_format='tf')
```

Then
we have to initiate a new instance for the subclass Model then compile and train_on_batch with one record and load_weights of built model

```
loaded_model = RecommenderNet(num_users, num_movies, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
loaded_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001))
loaded_model.train_on_batch(x_train[:1], y_train[:1])
loaded_model.load_weights('model_weights')
```

This work perfectly in TensorFlow==2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded tensorflow 1.14.0 to 2.2.0, save_model worked

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model,'./saved_model')
```

But with the load_model, after loading the model, while prediction

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./saved_model')
```

I get value error

```
rates = loaded_model.predict(user_product_array).flatten()

    ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
      inputs: (
        Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=int32))
      input_signature: (
        TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1'))
```

May I know the issue here?